# how to add more UIguestures in pagebased application

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

I am using page based application for one of my application.

There is a Uigesture is already working for swiping of pages where if you tap page will swipe.
But i want to add more gesture where if i tap some other functionality should work.

Example if i tap button bar should appear or if i tap zoomin should happen.

So how can i do this where already once tap swiping of pages is happening.I dont want swiping of pages to  happen instead i want other Uigesture to Work.

Comment: CocoaSDK has separate methods for each separate gestures.!!

Comment: @DeepjyotiRoy ya They have separate Gestures i agree with u,but page based application when u just tap page will swipe.so how can i add more Uigestures when already tap guesture is used???i want to add tap gesture for other functionality as well.But it overrides the present one rite??